# Passing a Map to IteratorItemReader

Tags: java, spring, generics

I've been having hard time figuring out how to pass a `Map` to the Spring's [`IteratorItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/IteratorItemReader.html)

Basically, what I have is this, where I retrieve data from remote API:

```
Map<Structure, List<Structure>> data = getData();
```

The problematic part is when I try to pass this data to the `IteratorItemReader`

`deleg = new IteratorItemReader<>(data)`;

The error that I'm getting is: `Cannot infer argument(unable to resolve constructor)`. Before, I was passing just an `ArrayList` to `IteratorItemReader` and it played nice. So, now with a `Map` I'm not sure what to do as I'm not really experienced with Java. Any help is appreciated. I have really no room for data processing at the place where `IteratorIteamReader` is invoked, so I need to find a way to just pass it a `Map` and then later process data in the different part of code.

Comment: How is `deleg` declared?

Comment: The deleg is IteamReader<Map<Structure, List<Structure>>>

Answer (score 1):

Map isn't Iterable but EntrySet is.

Use this-

```
IteratorItemReader<Entry<Structure, List<Structure>>> deleg = new IteratorItemReader<>(data.entrySet());
System.out.println(deleg.read());
```

Comment: When I pass entrySet() I'm getting 'Cannot infer arguments'

Comment: Could it be that the problem comes the fact that IteratorItemReader accepts only Iterable with one parameter, and the Set in my case contains two?

Comment: The code I added compiles just fine on my compiler. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, it works that way, but actually, deleg is Iterator, not IteratorItemReader

Comment: can you paste the code sinppet here. How deleg is declared and how you are trying to read the values?

Comment: Posting a bit more of the code would be really helpful... if you just need an Iterator, why do you want to instantiate a IteratorItemReader? You can get the Iterator that iterates over the Set of Entry with data.entrySet().iterator()

Answer (score 1):

The IteratorItemReader accepts only an argument that implements Iterable. A Map is not Iterable, but for example the entrySet of the Map is.

```
deleg = new IteratorItemReader<>(data.entrySet());
```

Comment: With that I'm getting now 'Cannot infer arguments'

Comment: Could it be that the problem comes the fact that IteratorItemReader accepts only Iterable with one parameter, and the Set in my case contains two?